# I have a wordpress plugin that uses a cron and that cron does not run when nobody accesses the page

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

Context: I am making a wordpress plugin that receives two parameters, a title and a prompt, and generates an article that should be published in a random time of between 120 and 180 seconds. More than one request can be made. The data is saved in a txt that contains the data Title, Prompt, RandomTime and Record Time.

There is a table in the plugin section that shows a countdown made in javascript that indicates how much time is left until the article is published and when it reaches 0 it should be published. Keep in mind that the countdown in js is only visual. The publication time of the articles is managed in the cron and in the get_article_y_publish() function

Theoretically, crons are executed without the user having to interact. But for some reason that doesn't happen.

Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Psychologist article generator
 * Description: Este plugin genera un artículo apartir de un título usando la API de OpenAI.
 * Version: 2.1 B
 * Author: Toni cipher
 * Author URI: https://cipher.icu
 */




// Ubicación del archivo
$filename = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'titulos_y_prompts.txt';



// Activación del plugin
function mi_plugin_activado() {
    // Agregar el horario de cron personalizado (si no existe)
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_custom_function' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'per_minute', 'my_custom_function' );
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'mi_plugin_activado' );

// Desactivación del plugin
function mi_plugin_desactivado() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'my_custom_function' );
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'mi_plugin_desactivado' );


// Función para crear la página de ajustes
function ammd_admin_menu() {
    add_options_page(
        'Administrar Títulos',
        'Automatización Artículos',
        'manage_options',
        'ammd-settings',
        'ammd_settings_page'
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'ammd_admin_menu');

// HTML para la página de ajustes
function ammd_settings_page() {
    

    global $filename;
    /*
    Este codigo es para mostrar cuando es el proximo tiempo en el cual se ejecutará obtener_articulo y publicar. Descomentar en caso de querer ver esa informacion.
    $next_cron = wp_next_scheduled('my_custom_function');
    if ($next_cron !== false) {
        // Formatear la fecha y hora de la próxima ejecución
        $next_cron_formatted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $next_cron);
    
        // Imprimir la próxima fecha y hora de ejecución
        echo "<h1>La próxima ejecución de 'my_custom_function' está programada para: $next_cron_formatted </h1>";
    } else {
        echo "<h1>La tarea cron 'my_custom_function' no está programada.</h1>";
    }*/
   
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if (empty($_POST['titulo']) || empty($_POST['prompt'])) { 
                return; // Sale del script si uno de los campos está vacío
            }
            

        
    }
    if (isset($_POST['titulo']) && !empty($_POST['titulo']) && isset($_POST['prompt']) && !empty($_POST['prompt'])) {
        // Limpiar el título y el prompt
        $titulo_clean = sanitize_text_field($_POST['titulo']);
        $prompt_clean = sanitize_textarea_field($_POST['prompt']);
    
        // Generar un valor aleatorio en horas entre 8 y 20
        $valor_en_segundos = rand(120, 240); // Valor en horas
    
        // Pasar a horas
        $valor_en_horas = $valor_en_segundos;// * 3600;
      
        // Calcular el tiempo de espera para este artículo
        $tiempo_espera = $valor_en_horas;
    
        // Obtener el tiempo actual en formato Unix (time())
        $tiempo_actual = time();

        // Ruta del archivo de tu script que se ejecutará periódicamente
        $script_a_ejecutar = __DIR__ . '/auto-post-v2.php';
        $tiempo_unix = time()+$valor_en_horas;

        // Convierte el valor Unix a un formato cron
        $minutos = date('i', $tiempo_unix); // Minutos (30)
        $horas = date('G', $tiempo_unix);    // Horas (10)

        // Configura el comando de cron con los valores obtenidos
        $comando_cron = "$minutos $horas * * * /usr/bin/php $script_a_ejecutar";

        // Ejecutar el comando para agregar el Cron Job
        shell_exec('(crontab -l ; echo "' . $comando_cron . '") | crontab -');

        // Crear la línea de contenido a agregar al archivo
        $nuevo_contenido = "\n" . $tiempo_espera . '||' . $tiempo_actual . '||' . str_replace("\n", ' ', $titulo_clean) . '||' . str_replace("\n", ' ', $prompt_clean) . "\n";
        file_put_contents($filename, $nuevo_contenido, FILE_APPEND);
        
        
        echo '<div class="updated"><p>Título, Prompt agregados con éxito!</p></div>';
    }

    // El código HTML para la página de ajustes
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<h2>Automatizador de artículos</h2>';
    echo '<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">';
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th scope="row"><label for="titulo">Agregar Título</label></th>';
    echo '<td><input name="titulo" type="text" id="titulo" value="" class="regular-text" required></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th scope="row"><label for="prompt">Agregar Prompt</label></th>';
    echo '<td><textarea name="prompt" id="prompt" rows="5" cols="50" required></textarea></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Guardar Título y Prompt"></p>';
    echo '</form>';

    // Nueva sección para mostrar los artículos y prompts en cola
    echo '<h2>Cola de Artículos y Prompts</h2>';
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Título</th>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Prompt</th>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Tiempo de espera</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';



    // Leer el archivo y separarlo en líneas
    $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $flag = True;
    if (!empty($lines)) {
        $acumulado_tiempo_espera = 0; // Inicializa el tiempo acumulado en 0

        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            list($horas2, $tiempo_registro, $titulo, $prompt) = explode('||', $line, 4);

            // Calcula el tiempo de espera para este artículo
            $tiempo_espera = $horas2 + $acumulado_tiempo_espera;

            // Actualiza el tiempo acumulado
            $acumulado_tiempo_espera += $horas2;

            // Resta el tiempo transcurrido desde el registro
            $tiempo_resta = time() - $tiempo_registro;
            


            $tiempo_espera -= $tiempo_resta;

         

          // Separar cada línea en título y prompt
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . esc_html($titulo) . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . esc_html($prompt) . '</td>';
            echo '<td><span class="countdown" data-tiempo="' . esc_attr($tiempo_espera) . '"></span></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }

            
            
            

        }
     else {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="2">No hay artículos o prompts en la cola.</td></tr>';

    }
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';  // Cierre del div "wrap"
    echo '<script>
    function startCountdown(element, totalSeconds) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            var hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds % 3600) / 60);
            var seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
            var formattedTime = formatTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
            element.textContent = formattedTime;
            if (totalSeconds <= 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                element.textContent = "Cuenta regresiva finalizada.";
            }
            totalSeconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }

    function formatTime(hours, minutes, seconds) {
        return String(hours).padStart(2, "0") + ":" + String(minutes).padStart(2, "0") + ":" + String(seconds).padStart(2, "0");
    }

    var countdownElements = document.querySelectorAll(".countdown");
    countdownElements.forEach(function(element) {
        var totalSeconds = parseInt(element.getAttribute("data-tiempo"));
        startCountdown(element, totalSeconds);
    });
    </script>';

    }







// Al activar el plugin, crea el archivo si no existe
function ammd_activate() {
    global $filename;
    if(!file_exists($filename)) {
        touch($filename);
    }

}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'ammd_activate');



function reemplazar_primera_linea_no_vacia($archivo, $nuevaLinea) {
    // Leer el contenido actual del archivo
    $contenido = file($archivo);

    // Iterar a través de las líneas y encontrar la primera no vacía
    foreach ($contenido as $indice => $linea) {
        $linea = trim($linea); // Eliminar espacios en blanco al principio y al final
        if (!empty($linea)) {
            // Reemplazar la primera línea no vacía con la nueva línea
            $contenido[$indice] = $nuevaLinea . PHP_EOL;
            break; // Salir del bucle después de reemplazar la primera línea
        }
    }

    if (!is_array($contenido)) {
        // Handle the case where $contenido is not an array, possibly by initializing it as an empty array.
        $contenido = [];
    }
    
    // Now you can safely use implode on $contenido
    file_put_contents($archivo, implode('', $contenido));
    
}
function obtener_acumulado_tiempo_espera($filename) {
    $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $acumulado_tiempo_espera = 0;

    if (!empty($lines)) {
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            list($horas, $tiempo_registro, $titulo, $prompt) = explode('||', $line, 4);
            $acumulado_tiempo_espera += $horas;
        }
    }

    return $acumulado_tiempo_espera /** 3600*/; // Convertir a segundos
}
function obtener_articulo_y_publicar() {
    global $filename;
 


    $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    if (empty($lines)) {
        // No hay artículos en la cola, detener la ejecución
        return;
    }

    // Obtener el primer artículo de la cola
    list($horas2, $tiempo_registro, $titulo, $prompt) = explode('||', $lines[0], 4);

    // Calcular el tiempo de espera para este artículo
    $tiempo_espera = $horas2;

    // Restar el tiempo transcurrido desde el registro 
 
    $tiempo_espera -= 60;

    
    if ($tiempo_espera <= 0) {   
        
        //Esta funcion es solo para registrar en un archivo si paso por acá el codigo. Si se usa descomentar la funcion crear_archivo_pase()
        //crear_archivo_pase();
        
        
        
        $tiempo_resta = 0;
        // Obtener el artículo, título y prompt desde el archivo .txt
        list($titulo, $articulo) = obtener_articulo_y_titulo();

        // Si no hay título o artículo, detener la ejecución
        if (empty($titulo) || empty($articulo)) {
            // Detiene la ejecución si no hay títulos
            return;
        }

        // Obtener fotos relacionadas con el título del artículo
        $foto_url_inicio = obtener_foto_unsplash('marketing'); // Ajusta el término según tus necesidades
        $foto_url_medio = obtener_foto_unsplash('business');  // Ajusta el término según tus necesidades

        // Generar el código HTML para las fotos
        $foto_html_inicio = "<!-- wp:image -->\n<figure class=\"wp-block-image\"><img src=\"$foto_url_inicio\" alt=\"\"/></figure>\n<!-- /wp:image -->";
        $foto_html_medio = "<!-- wp:image -->\n<figure class=\"wp-block-image\"><img src=\"$foto_url_medio\" alt=\"\"/></figure>\n<!-- /wp:image -->";

        // Dividir el artículo en dos partes
        $article_parts = explode("\n", $articulo);
        $halfway_point = floor(count($article_parts) / 2);

        $first_half = array_slice($article_parts, 0, $halfway_point);
        $second_half = array_slice($article_parts, $halfway_point);

        $first_half_content = '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $first_half) . '</p>';
        $second_half_content = '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $second_half) . '</p>';

        // Combinar las fotos y el artículo en el contenido del post
        $post_content = $foto_html_inicio . "\n\n" . $first_half_content . "\n\n" . $foto_html_medio . "\n\n" . $second_half_content;

        // Argumentos del post
        $post_args = array(
            'post_title'    => $titulo,
            'post_content'  => $post_content,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_type'     => 'post'
        );

        // Insertar el post
        $id_post = wp_insert_post($post_args);
        
        asignar_imagen_destacada($id_post, $foto_url_inicio);

        // Después de publicar, eliminar el artículo de la cola
        $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
        if (!empty($lines)) {
            unset($lines[0]);
            file_put_contents($filename, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
        }
        
       
        
    }
    else{
        $linea_de_texto = implode('||', [$tiempo_espera, time(), $titulo, $prompt]);
        reemplazar_primera_linea_no_vacia(__DIR__.'/titulos_y_prompts.txt',$linea_de_texto);
    }
}


// Agregar el horario de cron personalizado
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', function ( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_minute'] = array(
    'interval' => 60,
    'display' => __( 'Every Minute' )
);
    return $schedules;
 } );
 
 // Programar la función que se ejecutará cada minuto
 add_action( 'my_custom_function', 'obtener_articulo_y_publicar' );


// Programar la tarea cron
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_custom_function' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_minute', 'my_custom_function' );
}
?>
```

Comment: _"Theoretically, crons are executed without the user having to interact."_ - "real" crons, yes. But as https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/ explicitly tells you: _"WP-Cron does not run constantly as the system cron does; it is only triggered on page load."_

Comment: Here's an explanation how to hook it into the actual system scheduler: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/

Comment: @CBroe I am aware of the cron you are telling me about. The problem is that I need the user to download the plugin and without configuring anything it works correctly. As I understand the real cron, I cannot configure it from PHP. I have to use the server console, right?

Comment: Right, you need to set up a cronjob on the server for this to work. WordPress scheduled tasks, as CBroe pointed out, relies on traffic to work.

Comment: @cabrerahector Can you think of any solution that I can apply to achieve what I want?I am blocked :(

Comment: If you want stuff to happen at a specific time, using cronjobs is the way. CBroe's second comment links to an article that explains how to set them up.

Comment: @cabrerahector So making it run at a specific time without the need for the user to interact with the page, or having the end user configure a cron job, is impossible?

Comment: _"The problem is that I need the user to download the plugin and without configuring anything it works correctly"_ - if you want to use the system's cron/scheduler, the users will have to configure that themselves. (That you get the necessary console access from within the context of your plugin, is unrealistic - that would consider a rather huge security risk.)

Comment: The explanation I referred to, to "hook" this into the system scheduler, is only based on having the cron execute wget, to trigger the HTTP request to that cron endpoint - so theoretically, that could be triggered from the outside as well. There are some external providers for such "pseudo crons", that let you configure script URL and schedule - and then _their_ servers will make the request, to regularly trigger it on your (resp. your user's) site. (Could be an option for users who could not even configure cron on their system even if they wanted to.)

Comment: @CBroe I don't know if I'm understanding you correctly. But what you want to tell me is that I can use an external cron to load the page which makes the wp cron work. I can not do this. Since to load that page you need authentication for the wordpress account. From each user who uses the plugin. Sorry if I'm very slow. I'm new to this whole wordpress thing.

Comment: You need to requests the `/wp-cron.php` URL to trigger the process, and that is not protected by any authentication by default.

Comment: Oh thank you, I go to try that.

Answer (score 0):

WP_Cron, as commenters have pointed out, can only run when WordPress gets a request. The request can come from

1. a pageview initiated by a user.
2. a hit to any REST or other API on your site.
3. a hit to `https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron` (using your hostname instead of `example.com` of course).

So, you could have your Javascript countdown code do a [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to `/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron` when the countdown expires.  Something like this in your Javascript, NOT DEBUGGED!.

```js
    function startCountdown(element, totalSeconds) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            var hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds % 3600) / 60);
            var seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
            var formattedTime = formatTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
            element.textContent = formattedTime;
            if (totalSeconds <= 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                element.textContent = "Cuenta regresiva finalizada.";
                fetch('/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron')
                  .then ( response => return response.text())
                  .then ();
            }
            totalSeconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }
```

The `fetch()` sequence doesn't return any useful data, but it does give WP_Cron the kick it needs to work.

Be careful! activating cron too often can drag down site performance. And, this stuff is very difficult to debug.

All that being said, it's best to avoid relying on real-time WP_Cron operations.

Comment: I tried your solution, the problem is that for the javascript to run a user has to be on the page. And I want everything to work without the need for the user to be on the page.

Comment: Well, OK. If no user is looking at your website, then nobody will know your cronjob did not yet run. So the delay creating the post may in fact not be visible.